# Is 'worklight.db' used for Android apps for persisting cookies?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In a MobileFirst app I can see from JS code inside "worklight.js" that my app is using a SQLite file to store cookies.

However, from Chrome inspector I cannot find this file.

I am using IBM MobileFirst for **Android** and **iOS** apps.

```
        // The database file is in the application storage
        // directory
        var folder = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory;
        var dbFile = folder.resolvePath("worklight.db");

        try {
            this.conn.open(dbFile);
        } catch (e) {
            WL.Logger.error("Error opening cookies DB: " + e.message + ", Details: " + e.details);
            return;
        }
```

However, this code is inside object called `AirCookiePersister`

**I want to encrypt the SQLite file on Android devices.**

Code is found at:

[worklight.js](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/43117409/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you point to is only applicable for Adobe Air apps and not for Android & iOS. So, cookies won't be stored in `worklight.db`.

Comment: How did you know that? How can I make sure of that?

Comment: You said it yourself - that you're using Android. If you really want to verify, you can try it on an emulator and see the file system using DDMS